# Format Array values into 4x3 table

Tags: javascript, php, html, eclipse

I want to arrange my array value where the image can be display in 4x3 table format.

How do I achieve this?

This is a fragment of my array

```
$("#viewcase").append("<td><img src='" + serverURL() 
        + "/images/"+ arr[i].Case_Pic + "' height='100'>"
        + "<td>" + arr[i].CaseTime + "</a></b></td>");
```

This is my table body

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" class="uiresponsive" id="MyTable">
        <tr>

        <tbody id="viewcase">
        </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how my alignment looks like now

[Current Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEVs2.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to separate the image into tiles and distribute them in a 4x3 table?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen yeah, you're right. However, is it possible to do it without a border?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen i have tried out the code that u posted. However, the picture was align in one horizontal row instead of breaking the picture into 4x3 table format.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using simple CSS and HTML.

```css
.tile-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 0px;
}
.tile-table td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.tile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=TheAwesomePic&w=400&h=300");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: local;
}
```

```html
<table class="tile-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -0px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -100px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -200px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -300px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -0px -100px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -100px -100px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -200px -100px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -300px -100px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -0px -200px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -100px -200px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -200px -200px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -300px -200px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```